# SharePoint Online Masterpage change affects just on settings page

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-masterpage

I have a really weird problem regarding master page or `scriptlinks`.

In this case I edit the master page as you can see:

[image]

The problem is that this change just has an affect onto the settings page of the site collection.

This screenshot show the content of the settings page:

[image]

And this one on the homepage of the site collection:

[image]

As you can see the master page change just has an affect on the settings page.

But why?

Can someone help me please?

Thank you and best regards,

Atilla

Comment: Have you changed the path of the favicon in custom master page?

Comment: The favicon is in the location like in the masterpage (see screenshot 1). But it just affect as you can see on the next screenshots just on the settings pages of SharePoint.

Answer (score 1):

This is how it works in Modern UI. No more master pages or ASPX-pages that can me modified with SharePoint Designer. In Modern UI, you have much less options to customize pages - you can [add header, footer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/using-page-placeholder-with-extensions) and distribute web parts inside the content area.